# Wrong reputation sum after user was deleted

Tags: bug, reputation, voting, reputation-history

First, here's the screenshot:

[image]

Now, what's wrong:

I answered a question today, got 3 upvotes and had the answer accepted (so 45 points in total).
Then I deleted 2 user accounts for sockpuppet upvoting (not my accounts, I'm a moderator on that specific website :D ).
(Apparently the user that asked the question upvoted my answer from all 3 of his accounts).
The upvotes were reverted, but my dashboard still shows 4 actions (instead of 6) and the sum of the points is still 45 (instead of 25).
Here is the link to the answer: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/125148/146.

Side note:
The total rep for the day is correct.

Comment: That's because the system considers "user was removed" a different event from "upvotes and acceptings"

Comment: I kind of suspected that, but is this correct?

Comment: @Marius It is true that the system considers them different events.

Comment: @John. Thanks for clearing it. And indeed is not a duplicate, but the answer from the question shadow linked answers my question also.